# Cloud Functions for Firebase Logs Take so much time to show up?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I just write small Cloud Function to send notification to specific device and logs some message to console but it's show me that it's have been executed but logs really takes too much time to show up in Cloud Functions for Firebase logs, what exactly time taken to be shown in logs ?

Comment: About how much time goes by? Are you able to see the logs sooner using the CLI? The different methods for viewing logs are here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs

Comment: @JenPerson it's was taking about 3 hours in cloud functions logging & CLI and even stackdriver logging  but it's now is working fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seem to be working fine now logs come under one minute.